# How can i display the errors in customized forms in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I am displaying the fields in the temlate like this

```
<div> Name </div>  <div> {{ form.status }}   </div>
<div> Name </div>  <div> {{ form.name }}   </div>
<div> Description{{ form.description }}   </div>
<div> Sub category{{ form.subcategory }}   </div>
```

Now i want to have the div box where i can display all erros related all fields whether hidden or not

something like

```
{{ form.errors }}
```

is it possible

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You can display a error for each field of the form like **{{ form.name.errors }}**, where name is a field. But I do not think that it is possible to show something for ALL fields at once. What to show?

Comment: But i don't want for individual fields separately but one statement for all errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way for your code

```
<div> Name </div>  <div>{{ form.status.errors }} {{ form.status }} </div>
```

similarly for other fields of your form you have to write form.field_name.errors

for further information regarding form errors and their display please visit https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs

please do look for the latest documentation regarding the same issue.